# How to catch key pressed in event timout (Batch)

Tags: timeout, cmd

I'm using timeout event in cmd batch, but when it out of time, how can I catch the key that user pressed over event? or know that the time has out?

Something like maybe this:

```
@echo off
echo "Please press anykey to continue or Program will exit"
timeout /t 5
(
     if(timeout == true and keypress != "null")(
           goto continue         
     ) else (
           exit
     )
)
```

P/S: sorry for using some java code in this, because I still cannot imagine how it works in cmd batch (googled it but still can't.)

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the choice command.

```
choice /c abcd /n /t 5 /d defaultchoice /m "Please press a or b or c or d to continue or Program will exit"
if errorlevel 1 set choice=a
if errorlevel 2 set choice=b
if errorlevel 3 set choice=c
if errorlevel 4 set choice=d
```

The downside of choice command is that you can't press any key, you have to set all the keys that the user is able to press. There might be a better solution, though.

/t is for timeout

/d is for the default choice e.g. `/d a`

/n to hide the list of choices

/c abcd to set the avaliable choices to a, b, c, and d

Add /cs for case-sensitivity

Comment: I try that, but when run it in XP, it can't not recognize "choice" command. So only timeout can use. Can you help?

Comment: You _could_ get the choice program from Windows 98 or Vista onward in C:\windows\somewhere\choice.exe, or you can download choice from [this link](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA007219/dkclonesup/choice.html) or somewhere else and **place it in the same directory as the batch file that you are running**. This is because choice.exe was removed for Windows 2000 and Windows XP for some reason..

Comment: errorlevel 1 triggers when errorlevel is >= 1, so it should check in reverse order (4, 3, 2, 1)